# How to increase the value of a column by 1, every 2 rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to make a database which has two columns: the first being Team ID, the second one being Member ID. The second column is an auto increment.

How do I make it so that the Team ID is 1 for Member ID 1 and 2, but increases to 2 for Member ID 3 and 4, and so forth?

Comment: Use a trigger to set the teamid column.

Comment: TeamId = (MemberId % 2) + 1, So the column is unecessary...

Comment: No, I got it bum about face. Sound idea poor execution, oh well...

Comment: (MemberId + 1) div 2 @alvits was right. Perhaps we should second guess each other instead of ourselves. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) to update team_id to member_id mod 2 + 1:

```
CREATE trigger team_id_generator after insert on tbl 
for each row set team_id = member_id mod 2 + 1;
```

That will schedule execution every time a row is inserted. You will need to make sure member_id is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Two options. The first is to change the increment to 1 after the first row is input and then insert the remaining rows. The other is to update the entire table after completion and adjust the auto increment by -1.

```
UPDATE table SET memberID = teamID - 1  WHERE teamID > 1
```